# 2 css files? Theme css file gets override by another css file that I can not edit

Tags: css

I wasted quite some time already to fix this problem. I somehow have a Wordpress css file that overrides the css of my themes css. See attached image:

[image]

At the top is the css which screws with my design. Below is the color I would actually want within the css file of my theme. I can edit the 2nd css file, but how can I edit the other file?

Best regards

Julian

Comment: What is the other file? You’ve covered up the URL.

Comment: Click on that filename - it should show you where the relevant code is. I suspect it may be output directly in the page HTML below where your CSS loads. You can still override it by increasing the specificity of your selectors

Answer (score 0):

Make the CSS rule of style.css win over the rule of the other file.
To do so you can add the selector of a parent element of #header, or an !important after the color.
These two examples would work:

body #header{background-color:#ffe600}

#header{background-color:#ffe600 !important}

Better adding the selector of a parent element, rather than adding an !important.